# Camel route - Ignore return value

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, apache-camel

I have the following route:

```
    from("INPUT_QUEUE")
        .routeId("Test")
        .beanRef("logService", "save")
        .beanRef("deserialiser", "deserialise")
```

The "save" method in LogService returns an integer. I do not want this integer to be passed on to the deserialise method. I need the json coming from the input queue to be passed on.

Any help is appreciated and apologies for the simple question as I'm new to camel.

Comment: Can you also show implementation of your save method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [multicast](http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html) pattern, that allows to route the same message to a number of endpoints and process them in a different way:

```
from("INPUT_QUEUE")
    .routeId("Test")
    .multicast()
        .beanRef("logService", "save")
        .beanRef("deserialiser", "deserialise")
    .end();
```

Answer (score 2):

No the bean component will use the return value of the method as the new message body.

However you can use the language component and set it to not transform, something a like

```
.to("language:bean:logService.save?transform=false")
```

I can't remember the exact syntax, but I think you can use dot to separate the method name to call, as shown above

- http://camel.apache.org/language

Answer (score 0):

You can define your save() to have an argument like Exchange exchange

```
 save(yourExistingArguments, Exchange exchange){
     //performYourOperations and get your integer

     //However, do not set the integer in the exchange body.

     // exchange.getIn().setBody(integer)

     // Do not return the integer. Set the integer as state and make it accessible through getter and setter
```

That is all. Your message gets passed on as it is without the integer

Comment: I think what you're essentially saying is that the 'save' method should return 'void'. That will obviously work - I wanted to know if there is any way without changing the signature of the 'save' method.

Comment: why dont you create a wrapper method that invokes this method of yours and accepts the return value but still returns a void ?

Comment: Since you seem to have design constraints, you must also specify them in the question.